# How to debug Rails 4 API ajax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs

Ok, I've written an API using Rails 4 and Mongoid. I've added some validations to my `User` model like password can't be blank, minimum number of characters, etc.

When I try to create a new user via ajax (using Angular JS app frontend as well as using Postman to test the API) I get all the errors from the validation `"Password can't be blank, First name can't be blank, First name is too short (minimum is 1 character), Last name can't be blank, Last name is too short (minimum is 1 character), Email can't be blank, and Email is invalid"`

This is my validation on the `User` model:

```
...
validates :first_name, presence: true, length: { minimum:1, maximum: 50 }
validates :last_name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 50 }
validates :email, presence: true, format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false, message: 'Email address is already taken'}
validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
validates :domain, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, message: 'Domain is already taken' }
...
```

When I return the params using the following code in my controller:

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)
render json: { params: params, user: @user }
return
build_host_file(@user)
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: { success: true, user: @user } }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: { success: false, message: @user.errors.full_messages.to_sentence }, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

PS: Please note I've got a `return` in the create controller so I can see what's in the `params` variable

Rendering the `params` as `json` I get the following:

```
    {
  "params": {
    "user": {
      "first_name": "FirstName",
      "last_name": "LastName",
      "domain": "www.example.com",
      "password": "foobar",
      "password_confirmation": "foobar",
      "email": "something@email.com"
    },
    "controller": "api/users",
    "action": "create",
    "format": "json"
  },
  "user": {
    "_role": "user",
    "address_details": null,
    "auth_token": null,
    "bio": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "domain": null,
    "email": null,
    "first_log_in": true,
    "first_name": null,
    "last_login": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "notification_settings": null,
    "password_digest": null,
    "payment_details": null,
    "remember_token": null,
    "reset_digest": null,
    "reset_sent_at": null,
    "sign_in_count": null,
    "sign_in_history": [],
    "social_settings": null,
    "stripe_details": null,
    "telephone": null,
    "theme": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "id": "55eeb6bbfc7b340bdd000001"
  }
}
```

Any ideas of what's going on? Why am I getting error validation when in the `params` I get all the info?

Comment: Have you defined `user_params`?

Comment: I have. I believe I found the problem - strong params!!! - as the part that' giving me headache is a dynamic hash. I'm testing it now...